# Sticky header is not working correctly - offsetTop is null

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, navbar

```
import React , {useRef, useEffect} from 'react'
import './header.css'

const nav_links =[
    {
        path:'#home',
        display:'Home'
    },

    {
        path:'#about',
        display:'About'
    },

    {
        path:'#service',
        display:'Service'
    },

    {
        path:'#projects',
        display:'Projects'
    },

    {
        path:'#blog',
        display:'Blog'
    },
]

export default function Header({theme,toggleTheme}) {

const headerRef = useRef(null)

const headerFunc = () =>{
    if(document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80){
        headerRef.current.classList.add('header__shrink')
    }else{
        headerRef.current.classList.remove('header__shrink')
    }
}

useEffect(()=>{
    window.addEventListener('scroll', headerFunc)

    return ()=> window.removeEventListener('scroll', headerFunc)
},[])

  return (
    <header className="header" ref={headerRef}>
        <div className="container">
            <div className="nav__wrapper">
                <div className="logo">
                    <h2>Digency</h2>
                </div>

                {/* ========= navigation =========*/}
                <div className="navigation">
                    <ul className="menu">
                        {
                            nav_links.map((item, index)=>(
                                <li className="menu__item" key={index}><a href={item.path} onClick={(e) =>{
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                
                                    const targetAttr = e.target.getAttribute('href');
                                    console.log('test',targetAttr)
                                
                                    const location = document.querySelector(targetAttr).offsetTop;
                                    console.log('test2',location)

                                
                                    window.scrollTo({
                                        left: 0,
                                        top: location - 80,
                                    });

                                }} className="menu__link">{item.display}</a></li>
                            ))
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            
                {/* ========= ligth mode =========*/}
                <div className="light__mode">
                        <span onClick={toggleTheme}>
                        {
                            theme==='light-theme' ? (<span className='black'><i class="ri-moon-line"></i> Dark</span>) : (<span><i class="ri-sun-line"></i> Ligth</span>)
                        }
                        </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
  )
}
```

My problem here is the `onlick` mapped menu, the only button working is 'blog'. Rest of buttons throw this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'offsetTop')

I tried to build a sticky header with the funcion on every button to send me to the component (by distance of the outer border). I tried to log `console.log(targetAttr)` and every attribute is in the console. The problem is when I need to get:

`location = document.querySelector(targetAttr).offsetTop;`

Comment: What is the output of: console.log('test',targetAttr) ? Consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: hi Klian, the output is in the path of nav_links. sorry for my bad english. thx for that link i will read it.

Answer (score 1):

So your code is actually fine as seen here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-dewdney-5syxkr?file=/src/App.js

problem is you don't have HTML id tags in your code corresponding to ones you're trying to get (path properties).

Another approach you may look into is using `.scrollIntoView` - where you can add something like this which is much cleaner:

`document.querySelector('#blog').scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth'})`

Good article about using it in react is here:

[https://codingbeautydev.com/blog/react-scroll-to-element/#:~:text=To%20scroll%20to%20an%20element%20in%20React%2C%20set%20a%20ref,listener%20on%20the%20trigger%20element](https://codingbeautydev.com/blog/react-scroll-to-element/#:%7E:text=To%20scroll%20to%20an%20element%20in%20React%2C%20set%20a%20ref,listener%20on%20the%20trigger%20element).